# What is the name of this scale?

Tags: scales, terminology

I was noodling around on a piano (I'm not a real pianist) and I came up with this scale, which I liked:

> **C-Db-E-F-G-Ab-Bb**
> [image]

What is the name of this scale? Does it have a common name such as we find  with "the Hungarian Minor Scale" or "the Fraigish Scale" etc., or would we just name it based on its characteristics and alterations?

It is actually C Phrygian:

> **C-Db-Eb-F-G-Ab-Bb**
> [image]

**Except** it has M3 - **E**, instead of a m3 - **Eb**.

Maybe it should be called **Phrygian Major**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called [phrygian dominant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrygian_dominant_scale). It's the 5th mode of Harmonic Minor.

Comment: Yes - I realized after I wrote the question that M3 with b7 would make it dominant, not major.

Comment: Yet more "phrygian" complicated names for simple things! It's just *F harmonic minor*, in my money - I don't care what note it happens to start on!!!

Comment: @alephzero - Your money isn't worth much. In spite of your protestations, it is not F harmonic minor: it does not begin with F, has a b2 and **no leading tone**.  _I don't care what note it happens to start on_ - nor do I care what you do or don't care about. :) There's nothing complicated about "phrygian". There **is** something "complicated" about giving a scale the wrong name. _Everything should be made as simple as possible, **but not simpler**_ - Albert Einstein. That means you don't simplify when the simplication leads to error, which is exactly what your "simplification" does.

Comment: @alephzero - _I don't care what note it happens to start on_ - When the bank counts out your money, do you care which number they start on? If they were counting out 7 $100 bills for you, would you be OK with them starting on 4 instead of 1:  _400... 500...600...700 - **there you are sir - $700**._ ...

Comment: Also known as *Phrygian major* and *Spanish Phrygian*. So Stinkfoot was right all along!

Comment: @Tim - I like to be right :) - but  I do think dominant is more correct because of the M3/m7.

Comment: @Tim - I was reading through a list of scales today in Jazzology (good book) and he mentions this scale - calls it phrygian major - no other name. But I still think dominant is better.

Comment: @Stinkfoot - yes, it's more apposite with the *dominant* part, although it still has that M3, without which it wouldn't be major - or dominant.